# What sites are most played?

Tags: texas-hold-em, online

Where do most of you guys play?(online) I have been playing on ACR for a while now and just wondering if I should be looking for other options.

Comment: Pokerstars, partypoker, ggpoker, 888poker are probably all in the top 5.

Answer (score 1):

Tough question. Depends on region.

Worldwide (i.e: in the "free-world") I'd say Pokerstars is still king, although the competition is getting closer (PartyPoker is coming back, 888 is also doing fine...). Unfortunately, you can only access these sites with a VPN in many countries

In the Spain-France-Portugal restricted market, Winamax and Pokerstars take the biggest share, with 888 being a distant third and the rest barely having any traffic at all.

If you want more of a practical advice for choice, rather than just volume numbers, you may want to have a look at what [Pokerlistings](https://www.pokerlistings.com/online-poker-rooms) has to say

I have no clue what ACR is. Is it a USA site?

Welcome to our community, by the way!

Comment: Thank you, I have really enjoyed being here.

Comment: Yes I should have clarified, USA site.

Comment: @JillHemphill Well, the USA has its own specific situation. I don't really know much about it. Maybe Pokerlistings covers it, but I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

USA player here, David is right about worldwide, but the US is much different. I know of 3 sites in the US that are reputable (when compared to some other ones).

These are:

- BetOnline
- ACR
- Ignition/Bovada

I can't say for sure, but I have heard from several players that ACR has problems with bots in it's cash games, but at the very least the cash game scene is very nitty and full of regs. ACR has a good MTT scene if that is more your style.

BetOnline is a similar site with more fish in the micro cash games, I believe they have less frequent MTT's than ACR but it could be about the same. BetOnline is not compatible with pokertracker 4 so keep that in mind if you decide to check that one out.

Ignition/Bovada I have only played on a few times, They have lots of tournaments running but I dont have a lot of info on it.

All of these sites are available to US players and are known to be reasonably good with withdrawals, but they are not regulated so anything goes.